# Variation of Least Squares

Tags: least-squares

Given a linear system of equations $y=Ax$, the solution to the Lest Squares problem is the vector $\hat{x}$ that minimices the vector $r=y-A\hat{x}$. In my case, I am working in a problem in which I want to minimice the difference between the vector $r^{2}$ (this is, the vector of the elements of $r$ square) and a vector $m$ in which all the elements of the vector have the same value. I am trying to derive the expression but I got nothing. Does someone know how to do it?

Thanks!!

Comment: Is $m$ given?  You want to minimize the norm of $r - m = y - m - A x$. (We are minimizing with respect to $x$.)  Just let $b - y - m$ and minimize the norm of $b - Ax$ (with respect to $x$).

Comment: I have edited the question, I did an error describing the problem.

Comment: Oh ok.  I'm still not sure if $m$ is given in advance or not, though.  Do you know in advance the exact value of $m$?

Comment: Yes, $m$ is given. What I want to do is getting $\hat{x}$ so the power of the vector $r$ is as close as possible to certain known constant.

Comment: Do you mean you want the vector with the least variance (Hence constant)?